# why is Python asyncio `Task` constructor never called?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I am playing with Python asyncio library to try to understand its internals. For this, I downloaded the CPython source code V3.11.4. Then I added a print statement in the `__init__` of the `Task` class.

```py
#cpython/Lib/task.py

class Task(futures._PyFuture):  # Inherit Python Task implementation
                                # from a Python Future implementation.
    ...

    def __init__(self, coro, *, loop=None, name=None, context=None):
        ...
        print("Task.__init__ called")
```

after that, I created a script and executed it using the modified cpython version.

```py
#create_task.py

import asyncio


async def coro(sleep):
    print(f">>> running coro: {sleep} secs<<<")
    await asyncio.sleep(sleep)
    print(f">>> finished coro: {sleep} secs<<<")
    return sleep


loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
task = asyncio.Task(coro(3), loop=loop)
loop.run_until_complete(task)
```

```bash
$ $HOME/python3114/bin/python3  create_task.py
```

I got as output:

```bash
>>> running coro: 3 secs<<<
>>> finished coro: 3 secs<<<
```

I cleaned up cpython compilation environment by doing:

```bash
$ make clean
```

Then

```bash
$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/python3114 --enable-optimizations
$ make -j8
$ make install
```

And finally, I re-run the my script:

```bash
$ $HOME/python3114/bin/python3  create_task.py
```

I was expecting:

```bash
Task.__init__ called
>>> running coro: 3 secs<<<
>>> finished coro: 3 secs<<<
```

that's the only change that's not reflected after compiling. I have added some other print statements in the asyncio library and they worked as expected (they're printed to sdout).

for example, I added a print statemtent at:

```py
class BaseEventLoop(events.AbstractEventLoop):
    ...

    def run_until_complete(self, future):
        """Run until the Future is done.

        If the argument is a coroutine, it is wrapped in a Task.

        WARNING: It would be disastrous to call run_until_complete()
        with the same coroutine twice -- it would wrap it in two
        different Tasks and that can't be good.

        Return the Future's result, or raise its exception.
        """
        print("run_until_complete was called") # < ---- I added this print statement
        self._check_closed()
        self._check_running()
        ....
```

when I executed it after compiling, I got as outcome:

```bash
run_until_complete was called
>>> running coro: 3 secs<<<
>>> finished coro: 3 secs<<<
```

so it means that my compilation proccess is okay. What could I be doing wrong ?

Comment: `asyncio.Task` is a reference to a class written in C, you can use the class written in Python by using `asyncio.tasks._PyTask` - `task = asyncio.tasks._PyTask(coro(3), loop=loop)`

Comment: do you mean that's happening because of this: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d2340ef25721b6a72d45d4508c672c4be38c67d3/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#L363 ?
could you please elaborate more on this ?

because if I use: `asyncio.tasks._PyTask`, all the changes I do in the `Task` are reflected.

Comment: another thing is that `_PyTask` is available but I didn't see it in the `__all__` variable at the top of the `tasks.py` file.